# OpenLDAP extend ACL properly

Tags: openldap, access-control-list

I have a fresh installed server with this in it:
How should I extend the ACL to give a specific user write access a description property under a specific subtree of items?

More specificly I want to create a service user like: ldapagent that will be installed on client linux computers.

With this user I want to write computer's ldap entries but only the description.

So, I want to keep the existing ACL's + add this one rule. How?

thx

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write by anonymous auth by self write by * none
olcAccess: to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: to * by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write by * read
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, please:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write by anonymous auth by self write by * none
olcAccess: to attrs=description by dn="cn=ldapagent,dc=example,dc=com" write by * read
olcAccess: to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: to * by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write by * read
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. 

As I see you put the ldapagent before the line:olcAccess: to dn.base="" by * read

and I hav put it after it. What it the difference? Is it better as you did it, I am not sure the wokrings of how these rules should be.

many thanks, Csaba